# Is it possible to AJAX get the same url in HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I know that you can't do an AJAX request from HTTP to HTTPS so we are working on getting the served content available on both HTTP and HTTPS. Is there away to tell AJAX to get the file based on the protocol its using in the browser?

For example could you do:

```
....
type: "GET",
url: '//wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/jobopenings.json'
....
```

with the `//` would it serve up the correct version automatically?

Comment: Usually, yes. Though you could just do /wp-content and not worry about http vs https

Comment: Have you tried doing that?  Did it work?

Comment: I'll let you know, we're working on getting the content on both http and https first

Answer (score 2):

The [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) object can tell the current used protocol

```
url: window.location.protocol + url_without_protocol
```

But the same effect can be reached with [relative urls](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/HTML3.2/3.5.html)

```
url: '/path/to/whatever/you/want.json'
```

This will take the server root and stick your stuff after it, taking the protocol with it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var protocol = window.location.protocol || document.location.protocol;
```

Which you can then use for your url...

```
....
type: "GET",
url: protocol + '//your-address.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/jobopenings.json'
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/jobopenings.json`.  Note the single slash.

Starting the URL with `/` tells it took at the root of your domain (which will automatically use the correct http(s) protocol).